# Weak measurability of a set-valued map

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are compact metric spaces. Let $f:A\times B\to B$ be a Borel measurable map (in the sense that for every Borel set $S\subseteq B$, $f^{-1}(S)$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra of the Borel subsets of $A\times B$). Now fix a compact $S\subseteq B$ and define the set-valued map
$$a\in A\mapsto f^{-1}(a,S):=\{b\in B:f(a,b)\in S\}.$$
Suppose that $f$ has the property that $f^{-1}(a,S)$ is closed in $B$ for each $a\in A$. Is this set-valued map weakly measurable (i.e., for every open set $O\subseteq B$, the set $\{a\in A:f^{-1}(a,S)\cap O\ne\emptyset\}$ is a Borel subset of $A$)? If the answer is "not in general," is the graph of the set-valued map a Borel subset of $A\times B$?